# How to configure a language not supported in vscode?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Hello sorry I did not understand how to configure vscode so i can use it to work with a currently unsupported language. How do I define the highlighting, the use of the brackets and all the rest... The documentation is a bit vague ...
thanks a lot for your help

Comment: You don't "configure" it, you write an extension that supports your language: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/extensions/overview

Comment: If there is something you find unclear about the documentation you have to ask a more specific question, writing VSCode extensions is a very broad topic (and IMO the documentation is quite clear on how to do it)